# C# .NET HttpResponseMessage Sensitive Information found in memory

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient, dump, httpresponsemessage

How can I prevent sensitive information found in memory after a HTTP Request in C# .NET?

I have written a Console Application (net6.0) which makes HTTP Request. After executing the app, I took a dump (using Task Manager) and found sensitive information (Data in HttpResponseMessage and username, password submitted via the HTTP Request).

How can I prevent sensitive information found in memory? (something like, make sure those data is not in plain text in the dump)

```
class Program
{
    static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main()
    {
        try
        {

            Dictionary<string, string> values = new()
            {
                  { "email", "alex@bishan.me"},
                  { "password", "alex"}
            };

            FormUrlEncodedContent content = new(values);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://fake-api-jwt-json-server.tvbishan.repl.co/auth/login", content);

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Dump File**
[image: dump_file_img]

**PS:** I found some Stackoverflow questions regarding the same issue asked a couple of years ago. Unfortunately, they are not helpful to solve my issue.

Comment: Since these information are part of the request body that's why they present there. Use a different mechanism to provide credentials.

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes, I can use a different method to provide credentials (I mean username and password). But response has sensitive information like `access_token`, `refresh_token` etc.. I'm looking for a method to make sure that they are not in plain text in the dump.

Comment: If someone has access to your memory dump then you already have bigger problems to worry about.

Comment: @DavidG Good point :-D

Comment: @Bishan If the access tokens are short-living then the malicious person can't really abuse it.